# How to overcome past emotional trauma to concentrate in salat?

Tags: salat, depression

In recent years I have been through difficult times and had major emotional traumas. I noticed after that I no more find joy in *Salat* and *zikr*. I also no more read Quran in a daily basis as I was doing before. I'm taking some medications to fight the depression and psychiatric traumas But the treatment is not working well. I was doing well in my Iman and religious practice few years ago but recently I find myself struggling and fear I'm committing sins by being all the time mind absent and not feeling any joys or peace while praying or reading Qur'an.

I also developed a serious faith crisis similar to that experienced by Imam Al Ghazali. I'm not a giant thinker and philosopher like him but I feel I'm going through same faith crisis he experienced. I don't have the Intellectual capabilities of Imam Ghazali to overcome this crisis.

Are there any practical advice you can advise me to revert this dreadful feeling and state of mind?

Comment: To have concentration in Salat, you need to concentrate during Wothu, according to Hadith.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to love saying prayers (namaz)?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21813/how-to-love-saying-prayers-namaz)

Answer (score 3):

I am quoting from Allamah Tabatai, one of the greatest contemporary Quran commentator, faqih and philosopher whom was asked to introduce a practical way to increase the level of spirituality:

> In the morning, promise yourself to do only things that are good for hereafter and
>   Allah will be pleased with them. Anything other than that just leave
>   it whatever it may be. Every day before going to bed try to read Surahs Hadid, Hashr,
>   Saff, Jum'ah and Taqabon or at least Hashr. Also think for a few
>   minutes what you have done that day. If it were good say
>   alhamdullilah, otherwise repent and say Astaqfurillah. It is going to be
>   difficult for the nafs but it is very effective at the end.

Apart from this, one should always increase his knowledge on various topics in Islam, trying to better know the Allah, Prophet and the companions. This can be done by reading good books and hadith. Also bear in mind not to judge on the religion based on the behavior of Muslims. Even at the time of prophet there were many munafiq (hypocrite) among the Muslims. There are many verses and a full surah on that.

Finally, I advise you to keep away from the news for a few days and think what is happening to you at the personal level. Think what is driving you away from religion where you want to be at, try to pinpoint that. If that is crystal clear then you know what to do next.

Hope it helps,

Comment: i used to do these duas and prayers before sleep and when i wake up in the morning. but now i can't do them anymore b/c my mind is in a dreadful state. just telling me you have to do it is not a very helpful answer.

Comment: beside my emotional problems i feel i'm facing a faith crisis. I follow the political events that sweep the Islamic world recently and started loose faith in Islamist movements . the wrong behavior of many Muslims caused in me some disgust and made me enter a faith crisis.

Comment: @othman, answer updated