# How to love saying prayers / Salah / namaz?

Tags: salat, allah, imaan, love

I say prayers but it's like I'm just performing a duty. I feel nothing while saying
prayers like if my heart is close. I want to:-

- Say prayers with love.
- I mean I do not want to feel blank while saying prayers.

  My question is that how can I feel the connection between me and Allah? How to feel good after saying prayers and feel that I have done something really good. I mean,there should be a difference between saying prayers and not saying them. When I don't perform prayers,
  I feel only a little ashamed.
- Please also tell me to recite something to make heart soft.
- I don't have habit, but I do sometimes listen to music, does music makes heart like stone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a handful of common solutions to your problem sticking out in my mind right now:

1- The secret most people fail to notice is that one's presence of heart during  prayer is closely connected with their presence of heart during making Wudhu (ablution) for prayer. When making ablution take each and every action you make (e.g. washing your face, hands, etc.) as a metaphor of repenting from the sins of that part of your body. [Here](http://mawdoo3.com/%D8%AF%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%A1_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%B6%D9%88%D8%A1) is an Arabic post in which you can find dua's recommended to be recited when washing each part in ablution.

2-  Do not jump into reciting the Hamd Surah. Before reciting Fatihat-ul kitab in your prayer recite some opening (Istiftah) supplication. You can find some [here](http://mawdoo3.com/%D8%AF%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%A1_%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%AD_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A9). Reciting these can leave you some time for acquiring a more or less humble state before getting into your first Rak'ah. You can also repeat verses and zikrs of your prayer; this will help increase your attention to the prayer words.

3- Change the verses you recite after Hamd (Fatihat-ulkitab) in your prayers; Memorizing new verses can increase your attention in your prayer;Before reciting newly learnt verses in your prayer, try to contemplate on them to have a TASTE of what the verses are pointing to.

4- Seek help from other acts of worship.Needless to say, one's heart is not enlivened only by praying. Sometimes fasting can help. sometimes contemplating on Quran or simply listening to nice recitations of it may prove really helpful.

5- I'm saying this from firsthand experience: Eating too much, speaking too much and sleeping too much deaden the heart. Control them.

Comment: In the 5th point, you could write this way, *doing anything too much deaden the heart, or we're simply not made for that type of lifestyle, but Prophet (pbuh) commands us to **do anything regularly***.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very important question which many people have, but fail to ask.

Firstly, try to understand each and every word of your prayer by knowing what those words mean. Take the feel of what you say in prayer.
Then, try to read Qur'an regularly to attain fear of Allah and afterlife. The more afraid you are of Allah, the more you feel like you're talking to Allah.
Remember Allah much.

> And whoever is blinded from remembrance of the Most Merciful - We appoint for him a devil, and he is to him a companion. Qur'an 43:36.

Lay great emphasis on this line before you start your prayer.

> I seek refuge with Allah from the accursed satan.

May the creator guide us all

Comment: Can you please mention the ayah also?

Comment: @eva "So when you recite the Qur'an, [first] seek refuge in Allah from Satan, the expelled [from His mercy]." (Qur'an 16:98).

Comment: Can you mention in arabic?

Comment: http://quran.com/16/98 in arabic @eva and 'I seek refuge with Allah from the accursed satan.' is 'Auzu billahi Minaishaitanirrajeem' something like that...

Comment: Jazakallah khair

Answer (score 1):

Listen,
You have to strengthen your faith. You must ask yourself how can I be better and come closer to my lord. Then go step for step. Do the good and avoid the bad.
Stop listening Music. I know it’s hard at the beginning but you can do it. As more you
Do as more faith will rise.

Comment: As for music, they can replace it with great TARTIL recitations of Quran, specially those performed by Abdul-Aziz Salih Az-Zahrani (عبد العزیز صالح الزهرانی), Mansour as-Salimi (منصور السالمی), and MANY OTHERS. It was the Ramadhan before the last one when I found these recitations' links on youtube. I remember it was after a year when I realized I had unknowingly dropped listening to music for just about A YEAR! Thank god , I don't even feel like listening to music.