# How to pray on bus?

Tags: salat

How to pray when I'm outside of home, in a vehicle like bus? I do miss lots of prayers in traffic jam and journeys, and find it difficult to do all the kazza together at night. I'm so upset for that.. I don't know the procedure, can anyone please explain how to pray, and what if I don't have wudu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say wait untill you get off the bus, and pray as soon as you could.

You could 'catch up' the prayer, so to speak.

Atleast, That's what I do when I can't pray. (For example while in traffic)

Comment: thanks bro. so, will I pray as kaza while the recommended time is over? actually when I get out of home, it take the whole day for journey because of traffic jam here, and the prayer become kaza.. so i wanted to know about its solution.. :)

Comment: Yeah, Just pray as kaza if you can't make the prayer in time.

Answer (score 2):

How can you offer Salah in a bus? I mean even if you manage to find a [Sutrah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutrah) inside, like making the opposite person's seat as Sutrah, how will you do Sajdah, Ruku? Avoiding those main actions(performing properly)( unless you can't with serious health problems or unavoidable problems), are deemed must in Salah. Don't you feel people will be looking at you oddly, and moreover, you won't be able to focus properly on your Salah due to surrounding noise. Try to give Salah it's due importance and priority.

Helpful question: [How to love saying prayers(Namaz)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/21813/11938)

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: Oh, yeah, u r right; it doesn't seem to be feasible to do that in a bus because of ... / Of course as far as I can remember, s/he should wait to get off the bus then prayers (although s/he'll miss its on time thawab (rewards) (in emergency cases ..)

Comment: if you are sitting in a bus you don't need sutra as the next seat will be your sutra, have you ever heard of prayer by iyma' this is what @qdinar more or less suggested and this is the only practical answer i found here, if somebody has no choice then praying in a vehicle

Answer (score 2):

i was going/traveling(?) for 3 hours in train every week. in that case i was taking a bottle of water with me and take taharat in toilet, and make prayer staying in hall of wagon or sitting in chair; in both cases i did not sajda perfectly, that was allowed to me by some books or persons. it was said to me that i should pray sitting in direction of transport going, but i did not so; as train was going mostly in similar direction, i was sitting in direction which is more similar to direction to qibla.

in you case, if bus goes for several hours, i think you can ask people to stop bus and go to toilet and then, maybe even it is possible to get/make taharat in bus (when it is going) sitting near its door; alternatively, you can make taharat in toilet or near it (outside of bus), if people (in bus) do not blame you too much... also i recommend choosing the direction as i did; you can ask a person to swap places temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Wait until you get off the bus but if the time is over get off but if you cannot ... just pray in the bus. The direction is not important this times. Just move your head down instead of sajdeh.

Comment: This answer is in need of elaboration and more details. Please go through [answer] to see what type of answers are expected here on this site. And btw hello and welcome to [islam.se].