# Does kaza prayer have the same reward like faraz prayer?

Tags: salat

Does kaza prayer have the same reward like faraz prayer? What should one do if they end up missing their prayers e.g. for work/educational (or other necessary) purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option of kaza prayers exists for a reason. Try to pray on time, but if you are ever unable to due to circumstances beyond your control, try to make it up and pray kaza as soon as you can. Remember that God judges by intention.

The first Hadith from Sahih Bukhari (Volume 1, Book 1, Number 1):

> Narrated by 'Umar bin Al-Khattab (RA)
>
> I heard Allah's Apostle (SAW) saying, "The
> reward of deeds depends upon the intentions and every person will get
> the reward according to what he has intended. So whoever emigrated for
> worldly benefits or for a woman to marry, his emigration was for what
> he emigrated for."

Comment: InshAllah this is beneficial :) May God forgive anything wrong that I may have said.

Comment: Jazakallah khair(May Allah reward you with good).. this is helpful and inspiring information. We are grateful to Allah since he considers our intention.. May Allah help and guide us all..

Answer (score 3):

> Have you seen him who denies the Recompense? That is he who repulses the orphan (harshly), And urges not the feeding of AlMiskin (the poor), **So woe unto those performers of Salat (prayers), Who are heedless of their prayer**(Who delay their Salat (prayer) from their stated fixed times); (Qur'an 107:1-5)

The translation 'Who delay their Salat (prayer) from their stated fixed times' is given only by one translator Muhsin Khan, and all rest say 'Who are heedless of their prayer'.

But, anyways, Allah has fixed the times for our prayers and so does Prophet(pbuh) said so.

So, we must try our level best to offer the prayers in their fixed times.

**But,** you try praying this way, like praying Zuhr and Asr together, and praying Maghrib and Isha together, as the Prophet (pubh) did when he was traveling(today some schools of Fiqh and some shia's normally do this I guess). Because Islam, never puts unnecessary burden on the believers. You can try taking some time off as a beak of 10-15 mins from your work/education and try to request them. If they don't let you, then you can think of other alternatives(like praying Kaza, I'm not sure you can do this, as this is highly not recommended).

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: thanks .. actually sometimes i stay in bus journey or in a seminar.. then I had to miss prayers.. so i dont know when im in a journey in bus, how to pray?

Comment: Check out my answer... [Can we pray on bus?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23108/how-to-pray-on-bus/23234#23234)

Answer (score 0):

But putting 2 prayer together is just for traveling and sick people and shouldn’t done in the other times .

Allah says:{ إِنَّ الصَّلاةَ كانَتْ عَلَى الْمُؤْمِنِينَ كِتاباً مَوْقُوتاً} 
Translation: and praying at fixed hours is prescribed for the faithful.

Try to pray on time and get permission for 5 min prayer .