# Prayer prohibiting immorality

Tags: salat

in the Qur'an Allah says:   "Recite, [O Muhammad], what has been revealed to you of the Book and establish prayer. Indeed, prayer prohibits immorality and wrongdoing"

Qur'an (29:45)

so if one establishes the daily 5 prayers but still involves immorality such as adultery, does that mean his prayers are not accepted??

Comment: It would be good to mention which surah and verse you are citing.

Comment: You just need to copy paste a part of the verse in Google and you're [there](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=q9lSVbDKHdT08wfOvIHQBA#q=Recite%2C+%5BO+Muhammad%5D%2C+what+has+been+revealed+to+you) @Elyasin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so if one establishes the daily 5 prayers but still involves immorality such as adultery, **does that mean his prayers are not accepted??**

We cannot say for sure that ones prayers are not being accepted. But all I can is for sure, may be you're **not** praying/remembering God from the **bottom of your heart**. And....

> And whosoever turns away (blinds himself) from the remembrance of the Most Beneficent (Allah) (i.e. this Quran and worship of Allah), We appoint for him Shaitan (Satan - devil) to be a Qarin (an intimate companion) to him. (Qur'an 43:36)

So, it can be said that performing evil things in spite of praying can be said is a consequence of not remembering God from the bottom of your heart.

So, remembering Allah in the Salah, with complete devotion is as equally and more important than just praying merely.

Helpful, "[How to love saying prayers (namaz)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21813/how-to-love-saying-prayers-namaz?s=1%7C3.1952)"

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: This was all about a friend of mine, and your response is very convincing, thank you!

Comment: And don't forget to repent sincerely http://quran.com/4/17 @Sayid

Comment: A jazakallah khair would suffice @Sayid